# JavaScript for date range is only working with in a limit

Tags: javascript, date-range, wsh

I am trying to find the dates between two dates. I am attaching the script I have been using. It is working only if the start date and end date falls in between 4 months.  If it is more than that it is failing.

Input I am passing ("01/01/2019","06/01/2019",1).  What logic can I change here to get all the dates for larger date range.

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(fnGetDateListInDateRange());

function fnGetDateListInDateRange() {
   var addDays = WScript.Arguments.Item(2);
   var startDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
   var endDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(1);
   startDate = new Date(startDate);
   endDate = new Date(endDate);
//
   if (startDate > endDate)
     {
       return "-1";
     }
//
   var outputDate = new Array();
   var tmpDate = new Date(startDate);
 do {  
    outputDate.push(new Date(tmpDate));
    tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + parseInt(addDays));
   } while (tmpDate <= endDate);
//
  return outputDate;
}
```

Comment: What date did you pass that gave you an issue? And what was the issue? By the way is it vbs or js?

Comment: @AAA  It is JavaScript.  The variables I have passed are 
 ```("01/01/2019","06/01/2019",1)```

Comment: Your script is running fine without modifications. What is the failure you are observing and for what input values?

Comment: Here's a browser-based version of the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/89qetuya/ . The logic appears to be fine, all the dates are printed using the values you mentioned. Can you give us an example of a case which fails?

Comment: The same inputs.  But I am using Automation Anywhere (RPA tool) to run the script. It is running too long if the data range is too large and the script is erroring out after some time. It must be because of running it through Automation Anywhere.